# Calculate deviation of every new three values

Tags: r

I want to calculate the deviation of the means in my dataframe new. So here is my dataframe:

```
> new
       date                 count                  mean
1   2012-07-01            2.3498695             1.524178
2   2012-08-01            0.6984866             1.524178
3   2012-09-01            0.9079118             1.896867
4   2012-10-01            2.8858218             1.896867
5   2012-11-01            1.2406948             1.777372
6   2012-12-01            2.3140496             1.777372
7   2013-01-01            1.5904573             2.421820
8   2013-02-01            3.2531825             2.421820
9   2013-03-01            4.2962963             3.812503
10  2013-04-01            3.3287101             3.812503
11  2013-05-01            3.7698413             2.603770
12  2013-06-01            1.4376997             2.603770
13  2013-07-01            5.0687285             4.760392
14  2013-08-01            4.4520548             4.760392
15  2013-09-01            5.5063913             5.537038
16  2013-10-01            5.5676856             5.537038
17  2013-11-01            6.2686567             8.644863
18  2013-12-01           11.0210697             8.644863
```

Now I want to calculate the deviation of my means but in chunks of 3:

```
> sd(c(1.524178,1.896867,1.777372))
[1] 0.1902995
> sd(c( 2.421820,3.812503,2.603770))
[1] 0.7558814
> sd(c( 4.760392,5.537038, 8.644863))
[1] 2.055516
```

and add the deviation as a new column to my dataframe

```
> new
       date                 count                  mean     dev
1   2012-07-01            2.3498695             1.524178   0.1902995
2   2012-08-01            0.6984866             1.524178   0.1902995
3   2012-09-01            0.9079118             1.896867   0.1902995
4   2012-10-01            2.8858218             1.896867   0.1902995
5   2012-11-01            1.2406948             1.777372   0.1902995
6   2012-12-01            2.3140496             1.777372   0.1902995
7   2013-01-01            1.5904573             2.421820   0.7558814
8   2013-02-01            3.2531825             2.421820   0.7558814
9   2013-03-01            4.2962963             3.812503   0.7558814
10  2013-04-01            3.3287101             3.812503   0.7558814
11  2013-05-01            3.7698413             2.603770   0.7558814
12  2013-06-01            1.4376997             2.603770   0.7558814
13  2013-07-01            5.0687285             4.760392    2.055516
14  2013-08-01            4.4520548             4.760392    2.055516
15  2013-09-01            5.5063913             5.537038    2.055516
16  2013-10-01            5.5676856             5.537038    2.055516
17  2013-11-01            6.2686567             8.644863    2.055516
18  2013-12-01           11.0210697             8.644863    2.055516
```

P.s.: I somehow can't use the tidyverse package, so no chance working with tidyverse solutions.

Comment: chunks of 3 or 6? Your first three values of `mean` are `c(1.524178, 1.524178,1.896867))` or you mean chunks of 3 unique values ?

Comment: Chunk of three unique values `c(1.524178, 1.896867, 1.777372)`

Comment: Are all the values in `mean` column are always repeated ? Is it safe to assume first 6 rows would have 3 unique values, next 6 would have another 3 and as such? Or it is not necessary that it will repeat ?

Comment: Yes, safe to assume first 6 rows have three unique vales, next six also 3 unique values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ave` here and create a grouping variable taking every 6 rows in one group. Although we are taking 6 rows in one group we need `sd` of only 3 `unique` values hence `sd(unique(x))`.

```
df$dev <- ave(df$mean, rep(1:nrow(df), each = 6, length.out = nrow(df)), 
                     FUN = function(x) sd(unique(x)))


df
#         date      count     mean       dev
#1  2012-07-01  2.3498695 1.524178 0.1902995
#2  2012-08-01  0.6984866 1.524178 0.1902995
#3  2012-09-01  0.9079118 1.896867 0.1902995
#4  2012-10-01  2.8858218 1.896867 0.1902995
#5  2012-11-01  1.2406948 1.777372 0.1902995
#6  2012-12-01  2.3140496 1.777372 0.1902995
#7  2013-01-01  1.5904573 2.421820 0.7558814
#8  2013-02-01  3.2531825 2.421820 0.7558814
#9  2013-03-01  4.2962963 3.812503 0.7558814
#10 2013-04-01  3.3287101 3.812503 0.7558814
#11 2013-05-01  3.7698413 2.603770 0.7558814
#12 2013-06-01  1.4376997 2.603770 0.7558814
#13 2013-07-01  5.0687285 4.760392 2.0555158
#14 2013-08-01  4.4520548 4.760392 2.0555158
#15 2013-09-01  5.5063913 5.537038 2.0555158
#16 2013-10-01  5.5676856 5.537038 2.0555158
#17 2013-11-01  6.2686567 8.644863 2.0555158
#18 2013-12-01 11.0210697 8.644863 2.0555158
```

To understand how the grouping variable was created

```
rep(1:nrow(df), each = 6, length.out = nrow(df))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

---

I know OP doesn't need `tidyverse` solution but in case if someone in the future encounter this post and needs it they can use the below answer.

The logic is the same just converted it from base R to `dplyr`. The important thing here is to create groups.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group = rep(1:n(), each = 6, length.out = n())) %>%
  mutate(dev = sd(unique(mean))) %>%
  select(-group)
```

Comment: Just one question: If I wanted to do the same, but just with median instead of sd, do I have to change `sd(unique(x))` to `median(unique(x))`

Comment: @hpmurg yes, if you want `median` of only `unique` values then `median(unique(x))` would give you that.